# MongoDB using only map without reduce in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, join, mapreduce

In mongoDB i have two collection users and posts following this structure:

Posts

```
{ 
     _id: ObjectId(""),
     subject: "some post",
     content: "here is the content",
     user_id: "4351"
}
```

Users

```
{ 
    user_id: "4351",
    name: "John Marks",
    picURL: "http://...",
    aboutme: "historian of the future"
}
```

needing to get the posts in array with name.

```
db.posts.find().map(function(newPost){ 
newPost.name = db.users.findOne({user_id: newPost.user_id}).name;
return (newPost); 
})
```

I wrote this code and it's work in mongoshell well returning this result:

```
{ 
     _id: ObjectId(""),
     subject: "some post",
     content: "here is the content",
     user_id: "4351",
     name: "John Marks"
}
```

but i could not apply in php. You can't just simple get the output of the map function. It requires reduce function and output collection for the returning value.

Edit:

```
$map = new MongoCode('
    function(newPost) {
        newPost.username = db.users.findOne({user_id: newPost.user_id}).name; 
        return newPost;
    }       
');

post = $app->mongo->command(array( 
"mapreduce" => "posts", 
"map" => $map, 
"reduce" => '', 
"out" => array("inline" => 1)
 ));
 var_dump($post);
```

This code must be work but accessing another collection in map function via 'db' is forbidden after mongo 2.4 release. That's why i changed my approach. Instead of using map/reduce, handled with php. Added posts user_ids to array and get the users information with following code.

```
$userInf = $app->mongo->selectCollection("users")->find(
            array('user_id' => array('$in' => $user_ids)),
            array("_id" => 0, "user_id" => 1, "name" => 1, "picURL" => 1)
    );
```

Comment: i only found this type of using 

`$sales = $db->command(array(
    "mapreduce" => "events", 
    "map" => $map,
    "reduce" => $reduce,
    "query" => array("type" => "sale"),
    "out" => array("merge" => "eventCounts")));
`
it requires 'out' collection which used for result of reduce function.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/20621408/920379

Comment: So you haven't tried anything? Have you tried those examples leaving out the `$reduce` parameter or making an empty function to just fall through the pipeline.

Comment: i tried with only with map function as argument but while getting data you have to use that `$users = $db->selectCollection($sales['result'])->find();` 
so $sales['result'] is name of the new collection created end of the map/reduce process.

Comment: Whats the problem with using the `$users = $db->selectCollection($sales['result'])->find();` either that or you could try specifying inline in the out parameter with `"out" => array("inline" => 1)` and parse the resulting string.

Comment: okey i tried like that 
`$post = $app->mongo->command(array(
   "mapreduce" => "posts",
  "map" => $map,
  "reduce" => '',
  "out" => array("inline" => 1)
  ));

 var_dump($post);`
and get this error 
    `string(124) "exception: ReferenceError: db is not defined
at _funcs1 (_funcs1:1:49) near 't.username = db.users.findOne({user_id: n' "`

Comment: oh accessing to 'db' is forbidden after 2.4. it was only possible in local -_-

Comment: please edit your original post and include the entire code you are trying to run in php or link to it somewhere list gist. it is very hard to find out your issue when only looking at parts of your program.